# nlopt fails to compile cobyla.c with MSVC 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cl, nlopt

When I try to compile **nlopt** with Visual Studio Express 2013 using the provided Windows cmake files from the [website](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_on_Windows), the configuration via `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DNLOPT_BUILD_SHARED=On -G"NMake Makefiles" ..` in a `build` subdirectory works fine, but compiling via `nmake` fails with this error message:

```
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/nlopt.dir/cobyla/cobyla.c.obj
cobyla.c
e:\dev\nlopt\nlopt-2.4.1\cobyla\cobyla.c(1503) : fatal
 error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 228)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the l
ocations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'c:\MSVS12\VC\bin\cl.exe'
    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'c:\MSVS12\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'c:\MSVS12\VC\bin\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'c:\MSVS12\VC\bin\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
ERROR: Build script of nlopt failed with errorcode 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I tried building the CMake-generated nlopt project with VC12 (the compiler in Visual Studio 2013) in Release mode, I got a compile error C1001 in cobyla.c  The fix came from https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1028781/c1001-on-release-build.  I needed to put a #pragma before the offending line in cobyla.c.

```
i__1 = nact;
#pragma loop(no_vector) //line 1503
for (k = 1; k <= i__1; ++k) {
```

With this fix, I did not need to remove optimization flags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the optimization flag /O2 which causes `cl.exe` to crash. To compile cobyla.c with just /O1, perform the cmake step as usual, but then change the following file before starting `nmake`:

In the build directory open `CMakeFiles/nlopt.dir/build.make` and find the directive which builds `cobyla.c.obj`

There, at around line number 522 change

```
$(C_DEFINES) /FoCMakeFiles\nlopt.dir\cobyla\cobyla.c.obj
```

to

```
$(C_DEFINES) /O1 /FoCMakeFiles\nlopt.dir\cobyla\cobyla.c.obj
```

Then run `nmake` and it will build (while emitting the warning `cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/O2' with '/O1'`, but that is exactly what we wanted).